# List<T>.AddRange and the yield statement

Tags: c#, .net, list, foreach

I am aware that the yield keyword indicates that the method in which it appears is an iterator.  I was just wondering how that works with something like `List<T>.AddRange`.

Let's use the below example:

```
static void Main()
{
    foreach (int i in MyInts())
    {
        Console.Write(i);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<int> MyInts()
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

So in the above example after each yield, a value is returned in the `foreach` loop in `Main` and is printed to the console.

If we change `Main` to this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var myList = new List<int>();
    myList.AddRange(MyInts());
}
```

how does that work?  Does `AddRange` get called for each int returned by the yield statement or does it somehow wait for all 255 values before adding the entire range?

Comment: `AddRange` is called once and passed the result of `MyInts()` which is an `IEnumerable<int>`. The fact that it is _implemented_ using an iterator is transparent to callers.

Answer (score 5):

The [implementation of `AddRange`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,fb5985fca642071b,references) will iterate over the `IEnumerable` input using the iterator's `.MoveNext()` method until all values have been produced by your `yield`ing method. This can be seen [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,736).

So `myList.AddRange(MyInts());` is called once and its implementation forces `MyInts` to return all of it values before moving on.

`AddRange` exhausts all values of the iterator because of how is implemented, but the following hypothetic method would only evaluate the first value of the iterator:

```
public void AddFirst<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    Insert(collection.First());
}
```

An interesting experiment while you play around with this is to add a `Console.WriteLine(i);` line in your `MyInts` method to see when each number is generated.

Comment: You mean evaluated, not called I think. Also, nothing forces it to exhaust the enumerable. Because `AddRange` does so does not imply that all methods will.

Comment: `AddRange` is both called and evaluated once. And indeed, nothing forces anyone to exhaust the iterator but I understood that the question was asking specifically about `AddRange`.

Comment: I added a detail about how another method might not exhaust all the values.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** When you call `AddRange`, it will internally iterate every item in your `IEnumerable` and add to the list.

If you did something like this:

```
var myList = new List<int>();
myList.AddRange(MyInts());

foreach (int i in myList)
{
    Console.Write(i);
}
```

Then your values would be iterated twice, from the start to the end:

- Once when adding to your list
- Then in your `for` loop

---

### Playing a bit

Now, let's suppose you created your own extension method for `AddRange` like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AddRangeLazily<T>(this ICollection<T> col, IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    foreach (T i in values)
    {
        yield return i; // first we yield
        col.Add(i); // then we add
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
foreach (int i in myList.AddRangeLazily(MyInts()))
{
    Console.Write(i);
}
```

...and it would be iterated twice as well, without going from the start to the end both times. It would lazily add each value to the list/collection and at the same time allow you to do something else (like printing it to output) after every new item being added.

If you had some sort of logic to stop the **adding** to the list in the middle of the operation, this should be helpful somehow.

The downside if this `AddRangeLazily` is: values will only be added to the collection once you iterate over `AddRangeLazily` like my code sample. If you just do this:

```
var someList = new List<int>();
someList.AddRangeLazily(MyInts());
if (someList.Any())
    // it wouldn't enter here...
```

...it won't add values at all. If you wanted that behaviour, you should use `AddRange`. Forcing the iterationg over `AddRangeLazily` method would work, though:

```
var someList = new List<int>();
someList.AddRangeLazily(MyInts());
if (someList.AddRangeLazily(MyInts()).Count())
    // it would enter here...thus adding all values to the someList
```

...however, depending on **how lazy** is the method you calling, it wouldn't iterate everything. For example:

```
var someList = new List<int>();
someList.AddRangeLazily(MyInts());
if (someList.AddRangeLazily(MyInts()).Any())
    // it would enter here, plus adding only the first value to someList
```

Since `Any()` is true as soon as *any* item exists, then `Any()` just needs one iterationg to return `true`, therefore it just needs the first item to be iterated over.

I actually don't remember having to do something like this, it was just to play around with `yield`.

[Fiddle here!!!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FP3j8t)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

The behavior is different if the enumerable is for a class that implements ICollection, such as another list or an array, but let's say it doesn't since your example doesn't.  AddRange() simply uses the enumerator to insert items into the list one at a time.

```
            using(IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
                while(en.MoveNext()) {
                    Insert(index++, en.Current);
```

If the type of the enumerator is ICollection then AddRange first expands the list and then does a block copy.

If you want to see the code yourself:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,51decd510e5bfe6e